# How to map 2 @GetMapping annotations to the same URL

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I have this form in my view that generates the sudoku grid:

```
<div class="col-4 offset-4">
    <form id="sudokuBoard" method="post" class="form-group text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <table class="row-eq-height table-striped table-bordered text-center">
                <tr th:each="row: ${board}">
                    <td th:each="value: ${row}">
                        <div th:switch="${value}" class="col-xs-4">
                            <input name="cellValue" th:case="0" class="content form-control input"
                                   style="text-align:center" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"
                                   maxlength="1" value="0">
                            <input name="cellValue" th:case="*" class="content form-control input"
                                   style="text-align:center;background-color:lightgreen" type="text"
                                   th:value="${value}" readonly>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="gap-10"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Check Solution</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" onClick="window.location.reload();">New Game</button>
            <button type = "submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" id="solveBoard"> Solve Puzzle</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The `board` value is passed with this Controller method that hands over a solvable puzzle.

```
@GetMapping("/sudoku")
    String createSolvableBoard (Model model){
        sudokuGenerator.generateBoard(9, 20);
        sudokuGenerator.fillValues();
        model.addAttribute("board", sudokuGenerator.getMat());
        return "sudoku";
    }
```

I want to add another option to solve the puzzle automatically. This means the form has to be refreshed and populated with the solved board. My idea was to call another Controller method through the button click and send over the solved board but I can't seem to map both methods to `/sudoku` Spring won't let.

Is there any way to do this or should I just look at other options?

Comment: How would spring be able to know which method to call if it is receiving a GET for /sudoku but there are two methods mapped to that? That is why it is not going to let you do it. You could pass a boolean parameter to the GET and when it is true it is gonna solve it automatically.

Comment: Hi, it's more clear way to have two separate endpoints for getting the 'clear' and 'solved' boards. 
But you could also pass two model attributes: `'clearBoard'` and `'solvedBoard'` in your `'/sudoku'` request, and bind two separates forms to them. Just show/hide the one you need by a button.